# Can I increase the chance of stealing artifacts in castle sieges?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Someone stole my dynasty's ancient sword. I know that if I besiege their capital castle there is a chance I might be able to steal it back again. What is the actual percentage, and are there any factors which will increase this chance?